# Spatie media library pro - Can't resolve '@spatie/media-library-pro-vue2'

Tags: laravel-8, media-library, laravel-vue, laravel-medialibrary

Hi guys I am having trouble setting up Spatie Media Library pro. I am getting following error when I am building my resources with npm run dev

```
ERROR in ./vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary-pro/resources/js/media-library-pro-vue2-attachment/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@spatie/media-library-pro-vue2' in 'C:\Users\ermin\Code\ekupon\app\vendor\spatie\laravel-medialibrary-pro\resources\js\media-library-pro-vue2-attachment\dist'
 @ ./vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary-pro/resources/js/media-library-pro-vue2-attachment/dist/index.js 1:0-144 62:28-50 63:18-30 64:14-22 65:16-26 66:16-26 67:11-16 68:11-16 69:14-22
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/scss/main.scss ./resources/css/app.css
```

I am running Larvel 8 with inertia.js scaffolded with Vue.js (vue2).

This is my webpack config

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    output: { chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]' },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js',
            '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/src/js/route.js'),
        },
        modules: [
            "node_modules",
            __dirname + "/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary-pro/resources/js",
        ],
    },
});
```

Could this be package issue? Is anybody experiencing similar bug, or did I just miss something in my config?

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same issue. We tried to get Github packages to work in order to install **@spatie/media-library-pro-vue2** as an npm dependency, but it seems the packages are not published in the npm registiry.

This is the output from **npm install --save @spatie/media-library-pro-vue2**

```
Not Found - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/@spatie%2fmedia-library-pro-vue2 - npm package "media-library-pro-vue2" does not exist under owner "spatie"
@spatie/media-library-pro-vue2@^1.0.15' is not in the npm registry.
You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
```

The url they provide in their docs at the very bottom of [this page](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/handling-uploads-with-media-library-pro/installation) also doesn't show any results: https://github.com/orgs/spatie/packages?repo_name=laravel-medialibrary-pro

We already tried to contact spatie with support request and we are waiting for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Spatie released fix for this issue in their latest update